# Jquery Autosuggest formatting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Good morning everyone !

Just after some quick(?) help in formatting Jquery autosuggest options (Background colors).

Here's the sitrap:

Page1.php
Contains the search input field, and the Jquery code like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#headerSearch").autocomplete({
        source:'includes/searchAutocomplete.php',
        minLength:3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            document.getElementById("headerSearch").innerHTML = ""; //empty out the box so student ID cannot be seen
            if(ui.item.value > 0) {
                var label = ui.item.label;
                var value = ui.item.value;
                var id = ui.item.id; //This is where I can maybe store a color value?
                window.location='somePage.php?Profile=' + value;
            }
         }
     });
    });
</script>
```

Then of course, I have searchAutocomplete.php, which runs mysql queries to determine what the user is after. Depending on the available results, I want them to be coloured independently.. eg;

User searches for "johndoe".
searchAutocomplete.php finds that 'johndoe' is present in 3 things; a users email address, and 2 users usernames.
One of the usernames belongs to an account that is disabled. So it should be coloured differently to the active account.
Likewise the email address that matched 'johndoe' should also be coloured differently as it was an email-match.

I'm pretty great with PHP, but jquery is still pretty new to me. I'm sure I need to set another value, perhaps 'ui.item.id' on the searchAutocomplete.php page, then colour it accordingly on the original page.. or maybe I'm wrong here and that's why it won't work.

Any assistance in getting this sorted would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: This doesn't seem to be built in functionality for the [Autocomplete jQuery UI widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). You can, however, use the widget's source to build your own custom widget.

Comment: jquery is still pretty new to me :'( I wouldn't stand a chance at making my own custom widget

Comment: How are you planning to determine colour in javascript which you have shown? Are you going to store some flag in a variable here?

Comment: Hi j809, that's correct - On the autocomplete.php page I'm able to determine WHICH colour it should have, and then I need to pass it back to the front-end. This is the part I'm not sure how to do